# India - States and Union Territories

Tags: territory, administrative-division, india

India has 28 States, and seven [Union Territories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_territories). While States have their own elected Governments, Union Territories are directly controlled by the federal government.

1. What was the purpose of creating two different types of administrative division?
2. Why are the Union Territories not, instead, States?

Answer (score 6):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_territory) briefly justifies it as:

> Union Territories of India have special rights and status due to their
>   constitutional formation and development. They may be given this
>   constitutional status for reasons such as safeguarding the rights of
>   indigenous cultures of that region, averting political turmoil related
>   to matters of administration and so on. These union territories could
>   be changed to states in the coming times to exercise better control in
>   their administration.

Yet that text, only partly answers the question. [Here](http://parliamentofindia.nic.in/lsdeb/ls11/ses4/1321029705.htm) is a reference which is a first hand description of the reasons and proceedings.

In the above citation SHRI SRIBALLAV PANIGRAHI explains:

> There have been references  to  the  provisions  of  the 
>   Constitution dealing   with   the   Union   Territory,  statehood 
>   etc.  When  we  achieved Independence, we had nine regular States. At
>   that time, the States were coming under four categories. These were
>   Part 'A', Part 'B' and Part 'C' States. They were also called `A'
>   class, 'B' class and 'C' class States.
>
> In Part 'A', the States were nine in  number.  In  Part  'B',  we 
>   had Hyderabad,  Jammu and Kashmir, Madhya Bharat, Mysore, Patiala and
>   East Punjab. In Part 'C', we had five States, namely, Ajmer, Bhopal,
>   Bilaspur, Kooch  Bihar and  Coorg.  In  Part  'D',  only  one 
>   Territory, namely, Andaman and Nicobar Islands found its place. There
>   was a provision kept for future and if need  be and  if  we  acquire 
>   a  new territory in course of time, then that would join Andaman and
>   Nicobar Islands in Part `D' category.
>
> There was a dramatic change in this arrangement in course of time. 
>   As you  know,  there were demands from different areas for separate
>   States. There was also a Boundary Commission, the States
>   Reorganisation Commission. I  think the  Commission  was  constituted 
>   under  the  Chairmanship of Fazal Ali. P.M. Panicker was one of the
>   three Members of the Committee.  They  were  brilliant and  seasoned
>   people with experience in different areas. Their recommendations were
>   accepted and States were reorganised. And the old arrangement
>   disappeared and under the new arrangement, States and Union
>   Territories were formed.